# Differentiate empty from NULL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've got a table with measurement data in SQL Server 2005, one value per person and year, if available. My TSQL code fetches these values in a loop and processes them:

```
...
SET @val = (SELECT measurement FROM tbl_data WHERE persid = @curpersid AND yr = @curyear)
...
```

Now, for a certain person and year, the table can contain (i) a valid measurement, (ii) a NULL value or (iii) no corresponding row at all.

How do I differentiate between these cases efficiently? Both (ii) and (iii) will result in @val being NULL, so with the current code, they can't be differentiated...

Thanks a bunch for any hints, wwwald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bit of a hack, but:

```
SET @val = -99999  -- or some other value that will never occur in the table
SELECT @val = measurement FROM tbl_data WHERE persid = @curpersid AND yr = @curyear
```

Now, if @val is still -9999 then there was no row, or null if the measurement was null.

Comment: Thanks, the COALESCE solution seems optimal for me. It also allows me to keep using SET, which will warn me when multiple rows are returned...

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a value that measurement can never take, COALESCE() can used.

```
SET @val = (SELECT COALESCE(measurement, someValueThatDoesNotOccur) FROM tbl_data WHERE persid = @curpersid AND yr = @curyear)
```

No row: @val == null

measurement was NULL: @val equals somevalue

else a vlaid measurement

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check `@@ROWCOUNT`? However, this is a little bit risky, as you need to be sure not to do any other operations before you check `@@ROWCOUNT` (it updated after most operations).

Alternatively, read another column, like the primary key:

```
SELECT @val = measurement, @id = id
FROM tbl_data WHERE persid = @curpersid AND yr = @curyear
```

now check `@id` - if it is `NULL`, there was no row.

Comment: I prefer to avoid the @@ROWCOUNT to make the code a bit more robust. If someone insert a query in between, the whole thing would break.

Comment: I believe I both made that point and proposed a safer option?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'll probably go for the COALESCE option (see below) since it allows me to continue using SET. 
Thanks for the idea, in any case!

Answer (score 1):

I question why you are looping at all? Looping is a bad thing in SQL Server as it is a performance killer. Most things have a better set-based solution. Perhaps your problem has a better solution if you tell us what you are doing in the loop besides setting the value of a variable.